# Integration by parts in Bochner Lebesgue spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, lebesgue-integral, bochner-spaces

Does there exist an analogous of integration by parts for expressions such as:
$$\int_0^T {\langle u(t),v(t) \rangle }\, \mathrm{d}t,$$ where $u,v\in L^2([0,T];H)$, for some Hilbert space $H$?
If so, under what further assumptions on $u$ and $v$? Where can I possibly find some standard references in literature?

Comment: Proving this is actually a good exercise.  I'd suggest you give it a shot, and post here if/when you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard integration by parts in Sobolev-Bochner spaces is as follows. If $u, v \in \{ w \in L^2(0,T;V) \mid w' \in L^2(0,T;V^*)\}$, then
$$(u(T), v(T))_H - (u(0), v(0))_H = \int_0^T \langle u'(t), v(t) \rangle_{V^*, V} + \langle v'(t), u (t)\rangle_{V^*, V}$$
where $V \subset H \subset V^*$ is a Gelfand triple.

Evans probably has this. If not, you should read **Nonlinear functional analysis and its applications II/A (subtitle Linear Monotone Operators)** by Zeidler and Boron. Sections 23.2 are relevant.